# How to avoid duplication between mobile/desktop CSS while keeping maintainability?

Tags: css

Say I have CSS that looks a bit like this (This is pseudocode CSS, kind of):

```
@media-query for mobile {
    div {
        width: X;
        height: Y;
        display: flex-box;
    }
}


@media-query for desktop {
    div {
        width: W;
        height: Z;
        display: flex-box;
    }
}
```

Notice that width and height are different but display is the same for both. Now of course if it was this simple, I could relocate the display property from the media queries and be done.

But I have hundreds of lines of CSS for many, many selectors on a complex page, and using this strategy would result in it being somewhat difficult to maintain, in my opinion. I would always have to look back and forth between two different places to check the styling for a given element on mobile or desktop.

Are there any better solutions to this, or is this a case of 'suck it up, princess'?

Comment: Read about "mobile first". Basically, you start designing without media queries for mobile devices, then you add only media queries for the adjustements for higher resolutions using always more specific conditions for the query (like... no media query means any size, if later on the file you define "min-width: 500px" then that applies to 500 and above, later you add "min-width: 800px" and so on). Usually you'll have less "adjustements" for each resolution (it really depends on the design though, maybe on some breakpoint you need a lot of changes if the design demands that).

Comment: This question is way too broad (and/or opinion-based), and therefore off topic. Narrow it down to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As in one of the comments below your question , you can do this by building your project mobile first . This means you will start without `@media` and just build a normal page that is small. Than later , you can include a different `@media` for desktop . Something like this :

```
.searching {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 65px;
  background-color: $dark-grey;
  padding: 12px 9px 12px 30px;
  z-index: 6;
  border: 1px solid $red;
  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)';
    filter: opacity(0.9);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;

  input {
    padding: 7px 12px 6px 24px;
  }

  .s-magnify {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 7px 12px 8px 10px;

    &:before {
      transform: scaleX(-1) translateY(18%);
    }
  }

  button {
    margin-left: -5px;
  }

  @include breakpoint (tablet) {
    top: 100px;
  }

  @include breakpoint (phone) {
    top: 90px;
    padding: 12px 9px 12px 16px;

    input {
      padding: 5px 6px 6px 8px;
    }

    .s-magnify {
      padding: 5px 12px 8px 10px;
    }
  }
}
```